# Why are the White Walkers advancing?

Tags: game-of-thrones

What do the White Walkers in *Game of Thrones* have against the southerners or even the living that they are hell bent on killing them all? What exactly is their purpose? All they want is to conquer south of the wall, is that it? Also, is there any possibility that the leaders of the Walkers are dead important figures from the past, like Rhaegar or Rickard even?

Comment: Do you want an answer based on the current place the show's at or based on the information in the books? I'm pretty sure no one in the TV show knows why they're attacking... and, honestly, the TV show may branch significantly from the books by the time they get there.

Comment: @Catija I haven't read the books yet, but I do want to know the answers to my questions. Is it possible to get some answers on this without spoiling anything for anyone else? Yes, the tv show haven't said anything about them. Just some dramatic scenes, fables, convenient movements and that's it.

Comment: There's a lot of discussion over on our [sibling site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=white+walkers). It might have some info to tide you over until someone answers you here. We don't worry about spoilers but we do generally try to focus on the TV version, which wouldn't have an answer yet.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the pointers, I'll look for answers there as well.

Comment: @PEIN Short answer, no one knows, many theories, nothing final. Some say, they serve the dark lord, and the dark lord wants to take over the world starting with westeros. Others say the white walkers are simply a zombie race trying to feed. But in short we don't know yet. In fact I was upset to hear the series went as far as to show a battle with the white walkers whereas in the books, Jon is in a whole different situation...

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12009/who-or-what-are-white-walkers

Comment: @yondaime008 - I'm almost certain we'll see Jon fighting some White Walkers. Sam gave him so obsidian blades just before he left. You can't get any more Chekovian than that :)

Comment: @SystemDown with the way ADWD ended, I do have my doubts :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have read all of the books and can confirm:

> no one knows.
>    (well, technically someone might but it has not been revealed to the reader)

Comment: Especially Jon Snow doesn't kno--- ok, it gets old.