# White Walkers vs Army of the Dead

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

As we can notice by watching Game Of Thrones' episodes, **White Walkers** and **the dead men** are not the same, they have so many differences, can you please mention those differences, and why that the White Walkers are so much stronger than the Wights?

Comment: Very, very closely related: [Who or what are White Walkers?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/12009/11244)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[White Walker](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/White_Walkers)'s are an ancient race. They are powerful enough to manage hand-to-hand combat easily with a human. Normal swords can't kill or harm them. They have only two known weaknesses: [Valyrian steel](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Valyrian_steel) (dragonsteel) and [Dragonglass](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonglass) (obsidian). White Walkers can communicate using a laguage known as [Skroth](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Skroth)

[Wights](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wights) (or dead men or the Army of the Dead) are the minions of the White Walkers. They are like zombies and they can be killed only by burning them and are shown to be highly flammable. White Walkers can even revive corpses and turn them into Wights. Unlike the White Walkers, they're unable to talk and have a far lower intellect.

*Note: In the books White Walkers are also referred to as The Others. For more detail, refer to the Wiki pages linked.*

Comment: Somehow I managed to read all 5 books and watch the TV show without realizing this.  I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: @coburne may be because you read books first and missed it . and watched TV show with same assumption